# How to fix my code to find the average difference between a selected element and other elements in a column?

Tags: mysql

[employees table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixcde.png)Find the average distance between the house of the employee with ssn '123456789' and the other employee's houses.

I have written a code to solve this question but the answer is wrong. Can someone help me to fix my code and find the correct answer?

Select avg(abs(hno-hno1)) as AG from (select hno1 from employee where hno = ’731’) as hno from employee as e) as p;

The answer choices are:

a. 1133.37

b. 1295.28

c. 1133.38

d. 1162.34

Comment: Please do not include any links to your samples. Instead, include them directly in your question as `formatted text`

Comment: I attached a picture of the table containing the data to solve the question as someone might try the code in MySQL Workbench

Comment: @ Karan Hindocha    It is easier for us to copy/paste the data if you provide it as text in your question. Images are not a good choice. Also, many people here will not click on any links.

Comment: Alright. I will do that from the next time

Answer (score 2):

The sql is below and output would be **1295.28**

```html
select  avg(abs(hno-(select hno

from employee

where ssn = '123456789'

)))

from employee

where ssn != '123456789';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling like what you need is :

```
SELECT AVG(ABS(e2.hno - e1.hno)) as AG 
FROM employee e1
LEFT JOIN employee e2 ON e1.ssn <> e2.ssn
WHERE e1.ssn = '123456789'
GROUP BY e1.ssn
```

This query will compute the average difference of `hno` between employee having SSN `'123456789'` and the rest of the employees.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  avg(abs(hno-(select hno 
from employee
where ssn = '123456789'
)))
from employee
where ssn != '123456789';
```

Comment: So the answer would be b. 1295.28

Answer (score 0):

```
select format(sum(abs(mid(address,1,4)-(select mid(address,1,4)
from employee
where ssn = '123456789'
)))/7,2)
from employee
where ssn != '123456789';
```

This will give output value as 1295.29 which is correct one.